# If my Twitter account is private and I'm blocking a user, if I reply to that person's tweet, will they see it?

Tags: twitter, privacy

I have my account set as private and a certain person blocked.  However, her account is not private and it was brought to my attention she was speaking badly about me.  Under that specific negative tweet I tweeted her using that arrow on the bottom left to reply.

Will she get my tweet? Does she even get to see it? And if not, what about if someone else retweets what I wrote? Then will she see it?

Comment: If your account is private, no one can retweet your tweets.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your account is not only [private](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14016-about-public-and-protected-tweets) but you also have the user [blocked](https://support.twitter.com/articles/117063-blocking-users-on-twitter) they will not see any of your tweets. You should not even be able to tweet at them.

Take the example below:

I have a user named `@AnnoyingUser`. I blocked him. When I try to tweet at `@AnnoyingUser` they will not appear as a suggestion when typing their name, nor will it link the tweeted message to their profile. It will appear like the user does not exist.